# Programming & Software Development News / Newsletters

Tags: newsletter

I currently subscribe to MSDN Flash and Red Gate's developer newsletter, which is great. I'd like to find more sources. Where/Who else sends or posts news or articles about software development?

Comment: belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/)

has a nice weekly newsletter that features articles on various programming-related topics. Some are presentations of code submitted by contributors, while others discuss new developments in the software industry.

Answer (score 10):

- http://statuscode.org/
- http://www.hackernewsletter.com/

For more specific topics:

- http://html5weekly.com/
- http://javascriptweekly.com/
- http://devopsweekly.com/

Answer (score 3):

Everyone has his/her own favorite sites, here are my favorite sites:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/
- http://www.gartner.com/newsroom/archive/
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/programming
- http://mashable.com/apps-software/
- http://www.drdobbs.com/
- http://www.infoworld.com/news
- http://slashdot.org/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [NoSQL Weekly](http://www.nosqlweekly.com/) which features curated news, articles, new releases, tools and libraries, events, jobs etc related to NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these are the best but they're my favorites:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/programming
- http://devlinks.tumblr.com
- http://sidebar.io
- http://www.hackernewsletter.com